# Show that for integer $n\geq3$, $n!e$ is not an integer

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that for every integer $n ≥ 3$, the number $n!e$ is not an integer.

I have shown the inequality $\displaystyle0< \sum_{m=n+1} \frac{1}{m!} < \frac{1}{n!}$ for $n>3$

and I know $\displaystyle e = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$. Therefore $\displaystyle n!e  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{k!}$. How do I continue here. I tried to prove this by induction but I wasn't even sure how to show that $3e$ isn't an integer.

Lastly, how may I incorporate this result in the process of proving that e is irrational?

Comment: You forgot a faculty sign in the $n!e$ equality

Comment: Note that $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (n-k)!$ with every $(n-k)!$ being an integer, and the rest of the sum of $n!e$ is what you estimated to be a non-integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle (n!)\cdot e=n!\left[1+\dfrac1{1!}+\cdots+\dfrac1{n!}\right]+n!\left[\dfrac1{(n+1)!}+\dfrac1{(n+2)!}+\dfrac1{(n+3)!}+\cdots\right]=N+\dfrac{c}{n+1}$

where $c=1+\dfrac1{n+2}+\dfrac1{(n+2)(n+3)}\cdots$

$N$ is certainly an integer but not $\dfrac{c}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Split the sum into two parts:

$$ n!e = n!\big(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\big) + n! \big(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\big) $$

The first summand is an integer, because $\frac{n!}{k!}$ is an integer for $k\leq n$. However your inequality implies that the second summand is $<1$, but it's also positive and so must not be an integer. Therefore $n!e$ is the sum of an integer with a non-integer, so it is not an integer.

To see that this implies $e$ is irrational, if $e = \frac{p}{q}$ then $n!e$ should be an integer for $n\geq q$, but by the first part if $n\geq min\{3, q\}$ then $n!e$ is NOT an integer.